# how can i make dapp work on regular browsers?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, distributed-apps

I am trying to work on a dapp using Ethereum that works well for the normal end user (works on regular browsers like Ethereum without Metamask), is there a way to do that?. and how did https://stampd.io did it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MetaMask](https://metamask.io), or [Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases), or a similar DApp browser is **required** to interact with DApps. Without access to your Ethereum wallet, [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) library that is used in all DApps, won't be able to connect to Ethereum network and receive or send information.

In case of https://stampd.io, they're taking payments by PayPal, so they're processing Ethereum transactions internally. This looks a little scammy to me, because it undermines the integrity and openness provided for free by Ethereum:

[image: Pay with PayPal on Stampd]

Answer (score 1):

I've recently came across https://fortmatic.com

Seems to be a replacement for [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) that's compatible with web3 (your dapp would still work if it already works with MetaMask). Been testing it extensively and seems like it currently work with some web3 methods:

- web3.eth.sendTransaction
- web3.eth.getAccounts
- web3.eth.getCoinbase
- sendAsync personal_sign
- sendAsync eth_signTypedData

The modal interface is clean and it's relatively easy to get on-boarded with their docs.